# To use Page.Resources or MyControl.Resources in WinRT XAML?

Tags: xaml, resources, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I've noticed that some examples of WinRT applications conflict a bit in how they reference the resource settings

For some:

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage ...>
<common:LayoutAwarePage.Resources ...>
```

But I've also seen (Where LayoutAwarePage of course inherits Page)

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage ...>
<Page.Resources ...>
```

Which one of these is correct? What's the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source of the `LayoutAwarePage.cs` you'll notice that the `LayoutAwarePage` *is* a `Page`.  I think it's somewhat odd that they would reference the resources of the parent class and recommend you use `common:LayoutAwarePage.Resources`.

Comment: Where I see this is the Visual Studio templates use `Page.` while the official SDK samples use `LayoutAwarePage.`

Comment: They should do the same thing.  I just think using the child class rather than the parent class is a more clear way of doing it.

Comment: I'd say it doesn't really matter much as long as it works. I bet mixing parent and child class references comes from their modifying the templates at some point to start using the LayoutAwarePage, but neglecting to update the Resources properties since it still works as is.

Comment: @FilipSkakun That sounds like a plausible scenario

Answer (score 0):

How about `<FrameworkElement.Resources>`?  That way you never have to change the tag should you change the actual class of the Page/UserControl